# How to implement csrf token into ssr application with express? Seems like csurf is deprecated

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, security, csrf

I want to implement a csrf token into my application's server sider rendered web page but do not know how this process work and the package I found that tutorial's use is deprecated (csurf). How would I go about implementing csrf? Really need help :(

I tried watching many tutorial's so far and nothing that uses express and templates with a non-deprecated csrf package. So I'm really lost as this is my first time and I want to get it right.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Started using csrf-csrf on npm. Followed OWASP guidance on csrf. Link explains how to safely implement https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2uvrGQEy8i4.